# Changing the `from` address when sending an email through GMail

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, pear

I'm trying to use PHP Pear Factory to send emails through GMail in one project. It has been successful, but there is something that is not working 100% properly.

I don't know why if I set `$headers['From'] = 'from@domain.com'`, when I receive the email the From is username@gmail.com.

Find below the code:

```
$recipients = 'to@domain.com';

$headers['From']    = 'from@domain.com';
$headers['To']      = 'to@domain.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

$body = 'Test message';

$params["host"] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';
$params["port"] = 465;
$params["auth"] = true;
$params["username"] = 'username@gmail.com';
$params["password"] = 'password';


// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail_object =& Mail::factory('smtp', $params);

$send = $mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);

if(PEAR::isError($send)) { print($send->getMessage()); }
```

Answer (score 5):

In my own experience, GMail only allows the FROM header to be your own GMail account/address. When I tried to get it working with an address different from that, I couldn't manage to send out the email.

Comment: You're surprised Google isn't an [open relay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mail_relay)?  This isn't 1990.

Comment: Not suprised, just answered the question

Comment: I think you were surprised.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to authorize the from address in Gmail.

To do that from your Gmail inbox:

1. Click the **gear** icon and pick **Settings**.
2. On the **Accounts and Imports** tab click the **Add another email address you own** link.
3. Enter your info and pick **Next Step**.
4. Pick **Send through Gmail (easier to set up)** and pick **Next Step**.
5. Click **Send Verification**.
6. Click the link in the email you added.
7. Send mail from that from address!